# How to pass value of C# variable to javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In button click event I am writing this code.(code behind).I know button click event

```
protected void button_click()
{         
    string s1 = "Computer"; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    sb.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>"); 
    sb.Append("document.write('<table><tbody>')";); 
   sb.Append("document.write('<tr><td>Information</td></tr>')";); 
    if(s1 == "Computer" ) 
   {
     sb.Append("<tr><td>s1</td></tr>"); 
   }
   sb.Append("document.write('</tbody></table>')";);
   sb.Append(@"</script>"); 

}
```

It is working but I want value of s1 not s1.I know javascript is a client side programing.I wrote this function in button click event.How can pass value of s1 that is computer to table's cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
    if(s1 == "Computer" )  
   { 
     sb.Append("<tr><td>"+s1+"</td></tr>"); 
   }
```

Comment: When I click on button,table go to top position.I want it at bottom below buttom.I know when we use Table control in cs file like Table tb = new Table(); ,placeholder.control.Add(tb) is used.But how add dynamic table at perticular position,in this case?

Comment: Thats different to your original question.. You would probably best use ajax to add it without submitting the page, or, using a webform, submit the page and use the new value.

Answer (score 4):

simply

```
sb.Append("document.write('<tr><td>" + s1 + "</td></tr>');");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could change this line to:

`sb.Append("<tr><td>" + s1 + "</td></tr>");`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit irrelevant to the question you're asking. Your error has already been fixed by previous answers. But I will try to expand the asnwer further. If you wish to pass some value from C# to JavaScript, there're different methods.

1) You could make a protected method in a codebehind file and call it from your .aspx file, like

**my.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = '<%= GetMyValue() %>';
DoFooWithX(x);
</script>
```

**my.aspx.cs**

```
protected string GetMyValue()
{
    return "example";
}
```

2) If you wish to execute some JavaScript once page finishes loading, you could also do it from your codebehind like this

**my.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myScript = string.Format("myVar = '{0}';", GetMyVarValue());
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "MyVarSetter", myScript, true);
}
private string GetMyVarValue()
{
    return "example";
}
```